# Node.JS: Request a Key-Value from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, request

API_URL show something like this:

```
{
    "posts": [{
        "id": "987f2bhfzu3r3f43fg",
        "uuid": "g3g4g-4g34gd7f-40ae-96g43g82-65g34g43ccec94a566",
        "title": "This is my title",
        "tag": "thistag"
    }]
}
```

```js
const request = require('request');


request('API_URL', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body.posts);

});
```

Returns me

```
[{
    "id": "987f2bhfzu3r3f43fg",
    "uuid": "g3g4g-4g34gd7f-40ae-96g43g82-65g34g43ccec94a566",
    "title": "This is my title",
    "tag": "thistag"
}]
```

If I try `console.log(body.posts.title);` in my code it returns

> undefined

Who do I get the keyvalue of **title**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the square brackets (`[]`) - you have got an **array** with a single element. You first need to subscript that element, and only then access the field:

```js
console.log(body.posts[0].title)
// Here --------------^
```

Answer (score 2):

`body.posts` is an array so you need to iterate the elements to print the title like:

```
for(let post of body.posts){
    console.log(post.title);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `body.posts[0].title`. In json the square brackets indicate a list. I hope it helps.